# PHP Regex preg_match arguments from a specific function name

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-match

Let's say I have

```
$funcName = 'FooBar';
$myFuncString = $funcName.'("Arg1, Arg2")';
```

**How could I `preg_match()` so it returns `"Arg1, Arg2"` (with doubles quotes and without `$funcName`?**

I have tried:

```
$pattern = '/(?:'.$funcName.'|\".*?)\"/';
preg_match($pattern, myFuncString, $matches);
```

It returns `"Arg1, Arg2"` even if `$funcName` does not match. Any suggestions?

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `preg_match` stores what is captured.

Comment: @chris85 thanks for comment. Edited the question

Comment: So you want to match `$funcName` in the string? Your current regex has an `or` there. You also are using a non-capture group but I think you do want to capture part of this..

Comment: @chris85 I would like the result to be exactly `"Arg1, Arg2"` when the function is `$funcName`.

Comment: @chris85 but the result has to be specific to the `$funcName` (i.e not to return all arguments from all functions)

Comment: So maybe, https://eval.in/525839?

Comment: @chris85 Thank you. The result is similar to what AzizSaleh proposed. I think I should be able to work with that.

Comment: Your code actually worked you just had a typo, https://eval.in/525841. `myFuncString` != `$myFuncString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$funcName = 'FooBar';
$myFuncString = $funcName.'("Arg1, Arg2")';

//$funcName = 'NooBar';
$pattern = '/'.$funcName.'\("(.*)"\)/';
$matches = preg_match($pattern, $myFuncString, $res);

echo $res[1];
```

I had to add `$res` to the preg_match which has the results and correct the pattern.

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6de9d1236b82339199a2c64e914b5ca5b80e4e77

Comment: Thank you. It returns `[[0] => FooBar("Arg1, Arg2") [1] => Arg1, Arg2]`, how can only get the arguments with doubles quotes (`'"Arg1, Arg2"'`) and not the function name?

Comment: You should make the `.*` not greedy. If there were `")` later on this line it would match until the last occurrence.

Comment: @Wistar You echo `$res[1]`. @chris85 that is a good suggestion, my code assumes that that there aren't anymore `()`. The only time I see that is in minified/encoded php files.